# Custom wp_query function - search post content

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a php function that extends the default WP default search abilities (title & inside post content), it can now look in taxonomies / attributes too.

However, using the function results in the search query not looking inside post content, which is a feature I would like to retain. Would anyone be able to help tweak the below so the search still looks inside post content? Thank you

```
function and_extend_search( $search, &$wp_query ) {

    global $wpdb;
    if ( empty( $search ) ) {
        return $search;
    }

    $terms = $wp_query->query_vars['s'];
    $exploded = explode( ' ', $terms );

    if ( $exploded === false || count( $exploded ) == 0 ) {
        $exploded = array( 0 => $terms );
    }
    $search = '';
    foreach ( $exploded as $tag ) {
        $search .= " AND ( ($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '%$tag%') OR EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM $wpdb->term_relationships LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id WHERE $wpdb->terms.name LIKE '%$tag%' AND $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id = $wpdb->posts.ID ) )";
    }
    return $search;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have three errors here.

1. You put the parameter in your file as `&$wp_query` but you don't use this syntax in this case.
2. You clear out search `$search = '';` before you try to concatenate it.
3. Your condition is `AND` instead of `OR` - Unless for some reason you're trying to limit it?

```
function and_extend_search( $search, $wp_query ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( empty( $search ) ) {
        return $search;
    }
    $terms    = $wp_query->query_vars['s'];
    $exploded = explode( ' ', $terms );

    if ( false === $exploded || 0 === count( $exploded ) ) {
        $exploded = array( 0 => $terms );
    }
    foreach ( $exploded as $tag ) {
        $search .= " OR ( ($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '%$tag%') OR EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM $wpdb->term_relationships LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id WHERE $wpdb->terms.name LIKE '%$tag%' AND $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id = $wpdb->posts.ID ) )";
    }
    return $search;
}

add_filter( 'posts_search', 'and_extend_search', 500, 2 );
```